# Foreach more array by model function to view blade

Tags: arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, view, foreach

I am new in laravel and programming. i have a doubt to proceed in my idea.I have received 3 arrays from the model function and only want to create a foreach to display the concatenated array.
For example, display a point in the plane: X ,Y ,point name.
Do you have any ideas? Thank you.

I have succeeded with only 2 array '[$X,$Y]' but I am not idea to add new array in combination.

[image]

Model function:

```
public function getcoordsX() {
    $coppie=explode("§",$this->attributes['coordinateX']);
    $testi=explode('*',$this->attributes['negative_point']);

    $coppia=explode('*',$coppie[0]);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= count($coppie)-2; $i++) {
        $coppia = array_merge($coppia, explode('*',$coppie[$i]));
    }

    $X=explode('*',$coppia[0]);
    for ($j = 2; $j <= count($coppia)/2+1; $j+=2) {
        $X = array_merge($X, explode('*',$coppia[$j]));
    }

    $Y=explode('*',$coppia[1]);
    for ($j = 3; $j <= count($coppia); $j+=2) {
        $Y = array_merge($Y, explode('*',$coppia[$j]));
    }

    $testo=array($testi[0]);
    for ($k = 1; $k <= count($testi)/2; $k++) {
        $testo = array_merge($testo, array($testi[$k]));
    }

    $merged_data = array_combine($X, $Y);

    return $merged_data;
}
```

View blade:

```
 @foreach ($members->getcoordsX() as $X => $Y)
  
  <div id="myDiv" class="cardview" style="left: {{$X}}px; top:{$Y}}px;">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="section bi bi-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="8"/></svg>
      <div class="overlay">
        
          <!-- <div class="scheda">{{$testo}}</div> -->
      </div>
  </div>
  
  @endforeach
```

How do I add the third array and insert it into View Blade in a loop?

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on the ask, but can you add an example array format that is trying to be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved to create a new array with the first `$X` and the third `$point_name variables`. Then in the controller, I called this new array with a new function by model, and finally, in foreach `$X=>$Y` I wrote $point_name[$X].